# зачем писать sizeof в функциях?

Tags: c++, c

Всем привет,я не силен в си,и не понимаю,зачем в разных функциях записи указывать размер типа.Например:
Функция для записи в файл:

```
void put_rec(int rec[6],FILE *fp)
{
  int len;
  len=fwrite(rec,sizeof(int)*6,1,*fp);
  if(len!=1)printf("Ошибка при записи");
}
```

Так вот,зачем указывать размер sizeof(int)*6 при записи?Почему не хватит того что мы записываем массив из 6 чисел?Ведь этот массив все таки имеет размер и по нему нельзя понять сколько записывать?

P.s Шилдт пишет что размер sizeof() выполняется во время компиляции и в программе размер рассматривается как константа.

Про какую тогда машинную независимость пишет Шилдт когда она выполняется на стадии компиляции?

Comment: А вдруг вы из него хотите записать только 2 элемента? :) И еще - функция-то принимает *не массив*, а указатель, просто массив преобразуется в указатель на первый элемент, так что внутри `fwrite` размер массива не виден...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция [**fwrite(...)**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/) в качестве второго параметра принимает размер одного объекта в байтах. В качестве объекта может использоваться `char`, `int` или, например, `struct`. А третий параметр, в свою очередь, предлагает указать количество таких элементов.

В вашем случае – `fwrite(rec, sizeof(int) * 6, 1, *fp)` –  размер объекта равен `sizeof(int) * 6` (размер массива, который функция `put_rec` получает на входе), а всего таких элементов – один (единственный массив, соответственно). То есть `sizeof(...)` сообщает функции, что будет записано что-то, имеющее размер в `24` байта (`4 * 6 * 1`).

С таким же успехом можно слегка изменить вызов функции: `fwrite(rec, sizeof(int), 6, *fp)` (пишем `6` объектов типа `int`).

И да, компилятор заменит `sizeof(int)` на результат этого вызова в целях оптимизации. Писать так или по-другому – вопрос ***читаемости*** и ***переносимости*** программы.

Comment: В дополнении попробуйте сами узнать `int a[10];printf("%d\n",(int)(sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)));`

Comment: Не виден размер только если переменная была аргументом функции. Тогда она передаётся как указатель.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Исправил.